# Не получается простейший пример по регулярным выражениям

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Вычитал в уроках вот такой вот пример:

```
<?php

    $preg = '[a-z]{4}[0-9]{5}';
    $string = 'abcd12345efg';

    preg_match($preg, $string, $arr);
    print_r($arr);

?>
```

Как я понял, шаблон '[a-z]{4}[0-9]{5}' равен шаблону: '[a-z][a-z][a-z][a-z][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]'
Как не крутил, в результате получаю:

> Warning: preg_match() [function.preg-match]: Unknown modifier '{' in C:wwwreg.php on line 6

И такая ошибка возникает в случае, если появляется вторая пара фигурных или квадратных скобок.
Подскажите, что я тут делаю не так?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$preg = '/[a-z]{4}[0-9]{5}/';
```

Comment: вот спасибо :)

Answer (score 3):

Не забывайте также указывать начало и конец строки

```
$preg = '/^[a-z]{4}[0-9]{5}$/';
```

а то ваши выражения могут отрабатывать неправильно
в первом случае

```
343dfsa32134 //true
```

а во втором

```
343dfsa32134 //false
```

можно иногда очень долго намучится что бы понять почему регулярка работает не совсем корректно

Answer (score 1):

еще можно $preg = '/^([a-z0-9]{5,})$/';